# Get page load time in react by PerformanceNavigationTiming

Tags: javascript, reactjs, page-load-time

I used to get page load time in my react project by `window.performance.timing` but I found that This property is deprecated. so I tried to get load time by PerformanceNavigationTiming.
This is the code:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    const page_load_time = performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0];
    console.log(page_load_time);
    console.log(`${page_load_time.loadEventEnd}`);
});
```

`console.log(page_load_time);` give me an object that contains loadEventEnd
number in ms but `console.log(`${page_load_time.loadEventEnd}`);` gives me zero

1. Why zero?
2. Is this the right way to get page load time?

Comment: Did you figure this out @tahaamiri?

Comment: @fraxture Not yet

Comment: I think I might have had some success. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72907673/how-to-use-the-performancenavigationtiming-api-to-get-page-load-time

Answer (score 1):

TSX Way:

```
const perf = window.performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0];
const loadTime: number =
        (perf as PerformanceNavigationTiming).loadEventEnd -
        (perf as PerformanceNavigationTiming).requestStart;
```

JSX Way:

```
const perf = window.performance.getEntiresByType("navigation")[0];
const loadTime = perf.loadEventEnd - perf.requestStart;
```

Make sure to wrap this in a `setTimeout(() => {}, 0)` so the `onLoad` event completes first and gives accurate timing