# How can I monitor the amount of time it takes for the nextjs router to load a page?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, performance, logging, next.js

When I interact with a next.js page I often find that there is a significant delay between when I trigger a `router.push` and when the next page loads. What's the best way to get an accurate metric tracking this delay?

The router push seems to do real work, then navigate the page to the next view. Many of the traditional web metrics - page load time, largest contentful paint, first input delay - seem to be effectively gamed by this behavior. Because of the work that's already been done, the time from navigation to load is a fraction of the real wall clock time spent.

This might be a better experience than plopping a user on a page that's slowly loading, but the user still experiences a tangible delay. Is there any way to directly track this?

Comment: Does this help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72907673/how-to-use-the-performancenavigationtiming-api-to-get-page-load-time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use web vitals. this is next.js docs [measuring-performance in next.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/measuring-performance)

you can also read [NextJS Core Web Vitals - measure the Core Web Vitals](https://www.corewebvitals.io/pagespeed/nextjs-measure-core-web-vitals)

I think the one that you need is this:

> Next.js-route-change-to-render: Length of time it takes for a page to
> start rendering after a route change (in ms)

Comment: Thanks! The next.js docs are useful, but the article seems to only point to the gamed metrics (LCP, CLS, etc)